# For below code, after certain period i am getting -ve values as output for +ve integer input. can anyone please explain the reason behind this?

Tags: java, fibonacci, primitive-types

```
class fibonacci
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
int c = 0;
int num = 1;
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
while(num < 100)
{
 c = a+b;
 a = b;
 b = c;
 num = num+1;
System.out.println(c);
}
}
}
```

Output:
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181
6765
10946
17711
28657
46368
75025
121393
196418
317811
514229
832040
1346269
2178309
3524578
5702887
9227465
14930352
24157817
39088169
63245986
102334155
165580141
267914296
433494437
701408733
1134903170
1836311903
-1323752223
512559680  #+ve value
-811192543
-298632863 #-ve value

Comment: Overflow. Try `long` if you want to support more values. `BigInteger` if you need to support arbitrary values.

Comment: Use `long c=0;` instead of `int c = 0;`

Comment: It works, but need to declare  a , b  & c should declare as long , if not will get incompatible error.

Answer (score 0):

import java.math.BigInteger;

```
    class fibonacci

    {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            BigInteger  a = new BigInteger("0");
            BigInteger  b = new BigInteger("1");
            BigInteger  c = new BigInteger("0");
            BigInteger  num = new BigInteger("1");
            BigInteger testValue = new BigInteger("100");
            System.out.println(a);
            System.out.println(b);
            while((num.compareTo(testValue)==-1))
            {
                c = a.add(b);
                a = b;
                b = c;
                num = num.add(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
                System.out.println(c);
            }
        }
    }
```